# WebView in Android not showing web page styles

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to make an Android app display a website in a WebView, but only the website home page actually show content properly via the WebView, the other pages completely disregard the website styles and display content with a white background and blue default hyperlinks. I tested the same type of app on iOS and it works fine there. What can I do about it?

[image: Android version]

[image]

This is the method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.awesomestories.com");
}
```

Comment: have you enable JavaScript ? or try to use setWebChromeClient.

Comment: please post your code so we could provide a better solutions

Comment: Seems like some Path related issue. Your web pages are not able to access required css files and resources. Can you share your code snippet?

Comment: Ok added the method, the website works fine in any size including the iOS app so I know there is no issue on that side.

Comment: Could you provide an error log for the page?

Comment: I got this from the error log "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" although I know it is available on the site.

Comment: See updated method, it includes setJavaScriptEnabled but no change.

Answer (score 2):

Settings should be set. 
Tricks Like this:

```
    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

Comment: Made my day! Works like a charm. Please try this once!! :D 

Answer (score 1):

If you have kept Single Column Setting in WebView remove it, it will work just perfect.

```
myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

If you have not kept Single Column setting and still its not working, then check that you have enabled JavaScript or not, if not then enable it.

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I posted the method, I don't have that line to remove

Comment: thanks I tried this too but did not notice a difference, see my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Android WebView requires you to explicitly enable javascript.
Styles in the page may be loaded via javascript, and generally websites don't tend to work good without it, so enabling it is important and might solve your problem in addition to that.

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```